# Symbol is associated with the wrong namespace in a macro

Tags: clojure, macros, clojurescript

I have this macro:

```
(defmacro widget [msg-type value & app-key]
  `(defrecord ~msg-type [~value]
     Message
     (~'process-message [msg# app#]
      (let [state# (~@app-key app#)]
        (dissoc
         (->>
          (merge state# msg#)
          (assoc app# ~@app-key))
         :errors)))))
```

`Message` is a protocol defined in [a clojurescript dependency](https://github.com/krisajenkins/petrol/blob/master/src/petrol/core.cljs#L25), with a `process-message` function.

When I try to use `widget` like so

```
(ns my.cljs.ns
  (:require-macros [my.ns.macros :as macro])
  (:require [petrol.core :refer [Message]]))

(macro/widget A-Record a-field :a-key)
```

I get this error:

```
Bad method signature in protocol implementation, 
my.ns.macros/Message does not declare method called 
process-message ...
```

How can I get Message to refer to `petrol/Message` instead of `my.ns.macros/Message`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the power of the mystical ~' operator :)
I see you already invoked it for process-message, so perhaps you are already acquainted with why; but for the purposes of the answer, stuff in the backtick gets fully namespace qualified, where as evaluate quote puts the literal symbol in place.

```
(macroexpand-1 '(widget :a :b))
```

And the error message indicate that you need to `~'Message` if you want to avoid it having the current ns attached to it.

However fully qualifying Message with the petrol namespace would be a good move IMO

```
petrol.core/Message
```

That way you don't need to rely on it being referred in the ns declaration. Note you don't need to ~' it either.

Also I would be wary of (~@app-key app#) because app-key are optional... you could get nothing passed in which would call whatever #app is, which doesn't sound like something you want to happen. Similarly passing more than one seems wierd to. Maybe it should be a required param?